# How can I troubleshoot 'querySrv ETIMEOUT' error while connecting to MongoDB on Ubuntu using Node.js and MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://nehad:password_is_hidden@cluster0.vs9yyxw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  }
});
async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
  } finally {
   
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

This is the error that I am facing after running my nodejs server

Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vs9yyxw.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17) {
errno: undefined,
code: 'ETIMEOUT',
syscall: 'querySrv',
hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vs9yyxw.mongodb.net'
}

This code works completely fine on Windows and Mac.